# How to store a decimal value as a byte in a file?

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I'm trying to store a byte worth of decimal value in a file using Python3.

For example 200, now instead of using 3 bytes for each character, is it possible to store it as its binary equivalent which should only take a byte?

I have looked a lot into encoding but that didn't help.

Comment: The `struct` module is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: It depends on what you need.  `struct` is good, but for simple cases you can just convert to a bytes string:  `open('abc.bin','rb').write( bytes([200]) )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

One (as Tim Roberts indicated) is to make a simple `bytes` object out of the value:

```
b = bytes([200])
```

Another is to use the `struct` module. There's plenty of options for various data forms, but for an unsigned byte, use the `"B"` format specifier, like this:

```
b = struct.pack("B", 200)
```

Either way, you can then write the byte to a file (be sure to open as a binary file):

```
with open("out.bin", "wb") as f:
    f.write(b)
```